# How do you properly use gdb `set substitute-path` with ../ references at the start of it?

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm performing post mortem debugging on a core file. The build was done such that the location of the source code is referenced as ../../../../../_vcs in the core. I placed the source code in /_vcs (that is, at root). However, I cannot get the `set substitute-path` gdb command to work. How is this supposed to be invoked?

```
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6.1-114.el7
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00007f9f6fd37207 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6

(gdb) f 2
#2  0x000000000042c585 in SignalHandler (sig=11) at ../../../../../_vcs/trafficserver9/src/traffic_manager/traffic_manager.cc:935
935     ../../../../../_vcs/trafficserver9/src/traffic_manager/traffic_manager.cc: No such file or directory.
(gdb) set substitute-path ../../../../../ /
(gdb) l
930     ../../../../../_vcs/trafficserver9/src/traffic_manager/traffic_manager.cc: No such file or directory.
(gdb) set substitute-path ../../../../../_vcs /_vcs
(gdb) l
930     ../../../../../_vcs/trafficserver9/src/traffic_manager/traffic_manager.cc: No such file or directory.
(gdb) quit
-bash-4.2$ ls /_vcs/trafficserver9/src/traffic_manager/traffic_manager.cc
/_vcs/trafficserver9/src/traffic_manager/traffic_manager.cc
```

Note that I can list the file at the specified location after I manually substitute `../../../../../_vcs` with `/_vcs`. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to escape parts of the path?

(As a side note, I can work around this problem via `cd /`. Then the indirect `../` references stop at / and I can access the directory. But it seems to me that `set substitute-path` should address this as well.)

Comment: Did  you find a solution firebush?  I think I'm having the exact same problem.  When I try "ist", gdb reports "123 in ../../foo/bar/file.cpp".  I have set substitute-path ../../foo /full/path/foo but it doesn't find the file at /full/path/foo/bar/file.cpp ...  Is  some kind of rehash command needed?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this isn't a workaround that works in all cases, but I happened to have a directory that was as deep in the source tree as the original binary was compiled in.  (And if I didn't have such a directory, I could have made one.)  So, I used the `gdb` command `cd` into a place that the compiled-in path `../../foo/bar/file.cpp` would actually find the code.

At that point the gdb command `list` showed the source correctly.